# Plot radial heatmap in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have problems when plotting a radial heatmap in Python. I would like to plot values from pandas dataframe that has column `angle`, `distance` and `count`.
Values for `angle` are from -180 to 180. The `distance` are values from 0 to 20 and `count` tells the value count of that pair (angle, distance).

Example of one dataframe whith `df.head(10)`:

```
    angle   dist    counts
0   -180.0  0.64    1
1   -180.0  0.67    1
2   -180.0  0.68    1
3   -180.0  0.72    1
4   -180.0  0.75    2
5   -180.0  0.76    2
6   -180.0  0.78    1
7   -180.0  0.79    4
8   -180.0  0.80    1
9   -180.0  0.82    2
```

I would like to discretize these values so that, for example, I have bins with a width of 5 degrees and a distance of 0.25. And in the cell, the count for those values is summarized and then plotted as a radial heatmap.

For now I worked like this, I would define a pandas dataframe that imitates a matrix, whose columns are degrees from -180 to 180 (-180, -175, ..., 175, 180) and index values are from 0 to 20 with step of 0.25 (0, 0.25, ..., 19.75, 20)

```
degree_bins = np.array([x for x in range(-180, 181, 5)])
distance_bins = np.array([x*0.25 for x in range(0, 81)])
round_bins = pd.DataFrame(0, index=distance_bins, columns=degree_bins)
```

And then i would sum `count` values:

```
for row in tot.iterrows():
    _, value = row
    degree = value["angle"]
    distance = value["distance"]
    count = value["counts"]
    degree_bin = np.digitize([degree], degree_bins)[0]-1
    distance_bin = np.digitize([distance], distance_bins)[0]-1
    round_bins.iloc[distance_bin, degree_bin] += count
```

I also found solution creating bins using `groupby` and `unstack` which is much faster than using `for` loop:

```
counts = df.groupby(['distance_bins', 'angle_bins'])['counts'].sum().unstack()
```

But for now I just want to make ploting work correct.

Code used for plotting:

```
n = len(degree_bins)
m = len(distance_bins)

rad = np.linspace(0, 20.25, m)
a = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n)
r, th = np.meshgrid(rad, a)
z = round_bins.to_numpy().T
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
plt.subplot(projection="polar")
plt.pcolormesh(th, r, z, cmap='jet')
plt.plot(a, r, ls='none', color='k')
plt.grid()
plt.colorbar()
```

This code gives me empty histogram. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "an empty histogram"?  Do you get an error message or a warning? What are `z.max()` and `z.mean()`? Also note that the 'jet' colormap might look nice, but is [not suited for data visualization](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/).

Comment: The data wasn't displayed, even there was histogram matrix, strange bug. Now everything works after fix. Thanks for "jet" colormap advice, I will try alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.histogram2d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) to calculate the counts for each bin.  It has a parameter `weight=` where you can put the given counts per entry.

The heatmap can be directly plotted via `ax.pcolormesh` on a polar subplot. The angles need to be converted to radians to match the polar plot.

Optionally you can use `ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')` to tell where the zero should go and/or `ax.set_theta_direction('clockwise')` to change the turning direction.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# first generate some dummy test data
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['angle'] = np.random.randint(-180, 181, 2000)
df['dist'] = np.random.uniform(0, 20, len(df))
df['counts'] = np.random.randint(1, 5, len(df))

# define the bins
degree_bins = np.arange(-180, 181, 5)
distance_bins = np.arange(0, 20.001, 0.25)

# calculate the 2D histogram
hist, _, _ = np.histogram2d(df['angle'], df['dist'], bins=(degree_bins, distance_bins), weights=df['counts'])

# plot the histogram as a polar heatmap
plt.style.use('dark_background') # this makes the text and grid lines white
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10), subplot_kw={'polar': True})
ax.grid(False) # pcolormesh gives an annoying warning when the grid is on
ax.pcolormesh(np.radians(degree_bins), distance_bins, hist.T, cmap='hot')
ax.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: polar heatmap with weights]

Comment: This is by far the best answer for creating radial heat maps I have seen. Thanks!

Comment: Just another tip. In case you need a legend (or a colorbar) for your heatmap you can get it by modifying the above code as follows:

`plot = ax.pcolormesh(np.radians(degree_bins), distance_bins, hist.T, cmap='hot')` and then adding the following line.
`fig.colorbar(plot)`